# Apple iMac to India; Customs duty clarification

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, india

I am planning to take my Apple iMac 21.5" from Dubai to India.

Please clarify, do Indian Customs consider it TV, desktop computer or laptop?

If any of you have personal experience, please share.

Comment: Dunno the 'official' stat, but I'd bet money on it being a desktop. Under no realistic situation would you ever sit that on your lap.

Comment: @pnuts JFYI, there is an additional duty on TV's so they might just categorize it as a smart TV. Probably not, but should be aware of it

Comment: It's obviously a computer. Why would you believe they would consider it anything else?

Comment: Thanks, and is it dutiable? If yes then what %

Answer (score 4):

It should be considered a Desktop PC.

But, given its shape you could say its a monitor (if that is not obvious; if you dont carry in original box) and try to pass it off that way.

The issue is that most Customs people are pretty smart these days and wont be taken for fools, especially if your port of entry/ customs checking is a major city.

You are better off trying to be polite / nice to them, and make some excuse and say its an older machine that you brought home for your parents since you dont use it anymore.

Basically, be nice or look up the above customs rates and prepare to fork out the duty.. which will make it not worthy of bringing back.

PS: You did not mention whether you live/ work there or just went for a holiday/ business trip.

If someone was returning / migrating back, they could bring it back under TOR - Transfer of Residence, probably incur lesser or no duty (Which I have done before when I moved back from the US).

Comment: Also see https://nricafe.com/indian-customs-baggage-rules-2016-complete-text/ where Desktop PC is Annex III, different to TV which is Annex I

Answer (score 1):

Being an iMac, you can always say that this is a computer monitor....

Check the Customs Duty here [Duty Calculator](http://www.dutycalculator.com/popular-import-items/import-duty-and-taxes-for-computer-parts/)

You can find more information here [INDIA: CUSTOMS, TAXES and DOCUMENTATION REQUIREMENTS for IT PRODUCTS and SERVICES IMPORTS](http://web.ita.doc.gov/ITI/itiHome.nsf/9b2cb14bda00318585256cc40068ca69/a35aabb5287ccc6985256d070060939e)

Comment: Yes you can also say it's a chopping board. However you should assume that custom officers will be doing their jobs properly. Hence you might as well go ahead and tell the truth.

Answer (score -1):

Total customs duty on Desktop PC in India is around 16% of the cost of the PC.

Comment: Huh. Using the duty calculator linked by Jacky, I count 19% ...

Comment: Especially since your answer contradicts an existing one, could you give a citation for this information?